# How do I save a word document to my file system instead of printing it out?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my application I print my div to a word document like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=testme.doc");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/doc";
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
divExport.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Instead of opening it on the browser How would I go about saving it to a path? Generally when using ItextSharp I would declare the path and the existing template file.

```
private static string AppRelativePath_1page = "~/DesktopModules/MyFolder";
private static string AppAbsolutePath_1page = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(AppRelativePath_1page);
```

In this case there is no existing template file. How would I go about creating this file in my server folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a StreamWriter, and instead of writing to the `Response` object, write to your StreamWriter.

Answer (score 0):

you do it by using Streamwriter

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path))
 {                
    sw.Write(stringWrite.ToString());               
 }
```